# Question about consistency under byzantine peers of Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

hope you all are well.

I'm researching Hyperledger Fabric and have a question about how integrity of the network works when peers are byzantine.

In the documentation it states that: "State is maintained by peers, but not by orderers and clients" [1]. It also states that "As long as peers are connected for sufficiently long periods of time to the channel (they can disconnect or crash, but will restart and reconnect), they will see an identical series of delivered(seqno, prevhash, blob) messages [from the ordering service.]"[1].

In essence my question is: Does the orderers save a copy of all the blocks that they have delivered to peers? If we assume that they are correct then any correct peer that joins the network should be able to retrieve a correct sequence of delivers so that it can recreate the state correctly. However since the documentation also states that the state is not maintained by the orderers we could have a situation where incorrect blocks will be delivered to the newly connected correct peer from a byzantine peer.

This might not be an issue in practice since one would probably configure a newly connected peer to receive blocks from peers of the same organization and why would peers in the same organization attack each other. I'm just trying to understand how Fabric works and this seems like an attack vector to me.

Thanks!

References:
[1](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/arch-deep-dive.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric is not Byzantine Tolerance yet. The orderers use the Raft consensus mechanism that is Crash Fault Tolerant.

Comment: Let's say that you have implemented a byzantine fault tolerant protocol for the orderers and that they are correct. What then?